# BigQuery error "View X is self-referencing"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm migrating from legacySQL to standardSQL and I am getting an error on a relatively simple query that worked in legacy.

The error is "View myproject.mydataset.vw_1 is self-referencing".

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a.LineItemID
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    LineItemID,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE(`Date`)) AS Order_Year
  FROM
    `myproject.mydataset.vw_1`
  ) a  
LEFT JOIN
  `myproject.mydataset.vw_2` b
  ON
    b.Line_Item_ID = a.LineItemID
LEFT JOIN
  `myproject.mydataset.vw_3` c
  ON
    c.Line_Item_ID = a.LineItemID
```

There are 2 views (aliased b and c) left-joined to 1 subquery (aliased as a).

Note that vw_2 and vw_3 both return 1 column each (Line_Item_ID) and they both select from `myproject.mydataset.vw_1.  I suspect the issue has to do with these 2 views each querying the same view, but it seems strange that it would work in legacy and not standard.

If I comment out either the join to table alias b or table alias c, the query works and returns a.LineItemID.  It only gives the "view X is self-referencing" error when both b and c are joined.

I have tried replacing the joins to b and c with sub-queries like this that specify the column name Line_Item_ID but it gives the same error.

```
LEFT JOIN
  (select Line_Item_ID from `myproject.mydataset.vw_2) b
  ON
    b.Line_Item_ID = a.LineItemID
LEFT JOIN
  (select Line_Item_ID from `myproject.mydataset.vw_3) c
  ON
    c.Line_Item_ID = a.LineItemID
```

The definition of vw_1 is the following.  Note that it queries a date-partitioned table.  This view used TABLE_DATE_RANGE when it was legacy SQL.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `myproject.mydataset.orders_daily_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170101'
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear this way from what you posted, but is it possible that the star expansion of `myproject.mydataset.orders_daily_*` includes the view as well (prior to the filter on `_TABLE_SUFFIX`)? If that is the case, you will either need to give the views different names, or use a longer prefix for the wildcard table such that it doesn't include the views in its expansion.

Comment: No, that doesn't appear to be the case.  The orders_daily_ table is a normal date-partitioned table.  All fields are nullable in that table.  Is it possible that the date-partitioned table is strictly a legacy-compatible table?  From a BQ engine perspective, is the table itself considered legacy in any meaningful way?

Comment: If I replace vw_1 in sub-query a with a materialized table based on vw_1, I no longer receive the error when vw_2 and vw_3 are both joined.  However, I do get the error if I then add a 3rd joined view, vw_4.  In this case vw_2, vw_3, and vw_4 are all still selecting from vw_1.  The only thing that has been materialized is the view that was selected in sub-query a.

Comment: If it is date partitioned, then I expect to see a filter on `_PARTITIONTIME` rather than `_TABLE_SUFFIX`. It looks like you are using a wildcard table rather than a partitioned table. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  It is a wildcard table and not a date-partitioned table that is the basis of v1.  The union-ing of the table partitions does appear to be working well in all other queries that I have run.  For the time-being, I have created separate versions of v2, v3, and v4 that select from the materialized table based on v1 instead of the view v1.  The drawback is that we will need to run a job to materialize that table every day.

Comment: If you have a sample job ID for one of the failed queries, consider submitting a bug on the [issue tracker](issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) so someone can take a look into what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Elliot.  I just submitted the issue.